# destruct and construct a class in order to clean its members

Tags: c++, destructor

I have noticed that, in our codebase, there are some classes that are only used to hold data in their members. In order to clean the members, we call each class' clear() command. However, I've also noticed that, clean methods call other cleans and, which in cascade, results in calling clear() of std data types like string and vectors. Therefore, there seems to be a huge amount of redundant code written.

To minimize the amount of work in the reduction process I am planning to turn each clear method to the following. What are other details I may be missing and your suggestions?

```
void aClass::clear() {
this->~aClass();
*this = aClass();
}
```

Thank you

Comment: You're missing, in the above, is that C++ does not work like this. Have you actually tried to assign something to `this` like that, yourself? How well did that work?

Comment: clearing a vector can be as simple as adjusting its size. Deallocating and creating a new vector is a whole different story. Actually it is more work, not less

Comment: You're not allowed to assign to a non-existent object, for instance `*this` after you have destroyed it.

Comment: Using placement new instead to the assignment might do what you expect but the whole thing seems pointless. The assignment from a default constructed instance alone should "reset the members".

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, so, how do you mean? this = new aClass(); ? If this instance was allocated statically(which is), I am not sure of using new here.

Comment: Even if you fix the issues with the assignment, you're likely going to run into issues if anything fails after the destructor is run.

Comment: No, [placement new](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Placement_new) is different. It's the only way an explicit destructor makes sense.

Comment: @b.g.: I have a feeling that you're not that familiar with C++. No good C++ book that I know would advise this sort of recursive "cleaning". Note for example that `std::vector<std::string>::clear`  doesn't call `std::string::clear`; it calls `std::string::~string`. You also seem to know how to call a destructor, but you don't know about placement new. That's strange because the two go hand in hand.

Comment: The proposed approach may be bad but I'm not convinced that the question is. The downvotes seem a little excessive?

Comment: I'm not sure why the question was closed. It seems pretty clear to me what OP wanted and what they tried. And it seems clear what is wrong with the solution. It might be misguided, but the question seems fine to me. A question asking about bad code is not necessarily a bad question.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing that your call to the destructor is wrong here. You could simply assign:

```
*this = aClass();
```

However, then

- This is not what a `clear` method is supposed to do. You are creating a new object not clearing it. If you `clear` a `string` then no reallocations need to happen. Deleting a `string` and creating a new one is really more work, not less.
- As a corrollary to the first point, `clear` does not take parameters, while your constructor probably does. Again, default constructing a new instance is not what is expected from `clear` and sometimes it isn't even possible (when there is no default constructor).
- Moreover, lets say you do implement `clear` like this. Then the method adds nothing that the user of the class could not do with a call to a constructor. Instead `x.clear();` they could write `x = aClass();`.

Summary: If you have lots of code to `clear` objects in your code base, then this is very likely for a reason. Clearing an instance can usually be done with much less computational effort than creating a new instance. On the other hand if this is not the case, then there is no point in implementing a `clear` method (provided that there is an accessible constructor to create a new instance).

Answer (score 0):

> What are other details I may be missing

The destructor still clears the standard containers that are destroyed. Not only that, but it also re-creates them at a cost.

References to the cleared object will become invalid. This can easily lead to undefined behaviour unless you are careful.

> and your suggestions?

Write a normal function that doesn't involve the destruction of the object.

Answer (score 0):

Nooooooooooooooooooooo.

Don't do that.

The destructor isn't just a function that calls some operations on your members.

*It ends the lifetime of your object.*

Period. Full stop.

You cannot call the destructor then keep using the object. Invoking its assignment operator with a temporary doesn't bring it back to life, either; that just, well, invokes the assignment operator to change some values. Values that no longer exist.

There are a few cases where invoking the destructor is reasonable, but they all involve "very manual memory management" using placement `new`. There are basically no other acceptable times to do it.

Review the notion of object lifetime in C++.

If your copy assignment operator is correctly written, then just `*this = aClass();` is already fine for resetting your objects. You might also consider `aClass().swap(*this)`, with the appropriate move-capable `swap` being added to your class.

These are not "redundant" operations.